# Is it possible to have conditional IF statements in an Html and text email template

Tags: email-template

I have a custom field `MaxBath__c`, and would like it **rendered** (viewable) if it is not empty otherwise don't make it **viewable**. How to write `if` conditions in below email code to achieve that?

```
{!test__c.MaxBath__c} bath,{!test__c.Type__c} 
for {!test__c.Rent_Min__c} per month located at 
{!test__c.Cities__c} {!test__c.State__c},{!test__c.ZipsFinal__c}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use most of the formula methods you'd use in Visualforce, formula fields, etc. Here's one way you could write the first part:

```
{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Test__c.MaxBath__c)),Test__c.MaxBath__c&' bath,','')}
```

You could also use a Visualforce template instead, which is longer, but I feel is more legible:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(relatedTo.MaxBath__c))}" 
     value="{!relatedTo.MaxBath__c}&' bath," />
```

Be sure to test your templates before you use them by clicking "Send Test and Verify Merge Fields".

Comment: Thank your help contact object working fine but custom object not working please hep me

Comment: @sfdcfox can you please check the answer. Its not working. I checked with it 
and also please go through 
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162567/if-condition-is-not-working-properly-in-html-email-template

Comment: I don't think IF expressions work if the comparand is other than a text field; e.g. `{!IF(Contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail,'has opted out','has not opted out')}` always returns false regardless of the actual value of the checkbox.  Similar issue for number fields; did not test dates

Comment: @cropredy It should work, actually. If not, might be worth reporting to SF as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to print **max bath** when **max bath field on test object** is not blank,below code should work in your HTML template.

```
{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(test__c.MaxBath__c)),test__c.MaxBath__c,NULL)}
```

Comment: till now not completed my requirement please hepl me

Answer (score 0):

If helpful for latecomers, @Samir solution worked for me in a like situation to *if there's a name, display 'Dear Name' and if there's not, display 'Dear Friend'* and it looks like this:

`!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Contact.FirstName)),Contact.FirstName,"Friend")}`