# IF condition is not working properly in HTML email template

Tags: email-template, if

My requirement is some what exactly like [**this post**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162397/is-it-possible-to-have-conditional-if-statements-in-an-html-and-text-email-templ). But the difference is, when `MaxBath__c` field not viewable(Which means `MaxBath__C` field have null value), then i should show some symbol like **#**.

I checked with the answer which the [Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162397/is-it-possible-to-have-conditional-if-statements-in-an-html-and-text-email-templ) has, but those are fails in result.

Please help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: This is not working for you? `{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Test__c.MaxBath__c)),Test__c.MaxBath__c, '#')}`

Comment: @MartinLezer I gone through the condition what you posted. But given fault result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of <http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162397/is-it-possible-to-have-conditional-if-statements-in-an-html-and-text-email-templ/162402?noredirect=1#comment242408_162402>

Comment: @Samir I already checked your answer in that link which posted by you.
and already mentioned in question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be basically the same thing, just put a `'#'` character as the result when the conditional clause is false.

```
{!NullValue(Test__c.MaxBath__c,'#')}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54580/discussion-on-answer-by-martin-if-condition-is-not-working-properly-in-html-emai).